# Event trigger after some hours

Tags: timer, cron, producer-consumer

I have an event orchestrator service which is basically a consumer of the pub/sub model. Whenever it receives an event of a particular type, it needs to trigger another event but with a delay of 48 hours. This should also come with a retry mechanism.

Now, the basic impelementation which came to my mind is creating an entry for the event in another table along with a timestamp and schedule a cron job at a particular time in the day which will check for the condition current time - timestamp > t (48 hrs). Is there any other way by which we can do? Like the use of lambdas and step functions.

Comment: Another approach is to have the orchestrator keep a list of events to trigger along with the time the event should be triggered, then publish the event so that the appropriate process or thread acts on the event when it is published.